# What is a good icon to represent a toll?

Tags: icon, google-material-design

I'm looking for an icon to represent a toll.

I found this icon on [Material Design](https://www.material.io/) under "[toll](https://www.material.io/resources/icons/?search=toll&icon=history&style=baseline)", I'm actually curious as the only thing I see is a circle and another part of a circle.

I'm thinking that it's possibly a coin going in a coin slot, but still seems a bit weird.

[image: toll]

---

My question has two parts;

1. How does this represent a "toll"?
2. What is a good icon ro represent a toll?

Comment: This looks like the most minimalistic version, but I think you're spot on - coin going to slot

Comment: [We all pay a toll](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ69p3oLkBigtTcDKwFo3mUyfmcL6tXfq6SNnw4jvWcAgk3YTVV&s) `:)`

Comment: Too short for an answer, but I always thought a car and a coin expressed "toll" well. Lots of icons out there for it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toll), a toll could be either

1. a tax or fee paid for some liberty or privilege (as of passing over a highway or bridge)
2. compensation for services rendered: such as
   a) a charge for transportation
   b) a charge for a long-distance telephone call

I suppose the icon you found is the most minimalistic version of a coin going into a slot. Perhaps for a slightly more representative but still generic version you could add a hand like in the icon [I found below](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=toll):

[image]

for a more road-specific type of toll you could add the "coin" together with a road:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the circles idea, but make it look less abstract and more like a coin. Also, it needs to suggest the coin is falling, because that's what it does when you put it into the machine, so the second 'half-circle' should be a bit below the coin, not on the side of it, somehow indicating the coin is actually going down, as in falling.

[image]